# Parse Failed with: TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I keep getting this error Failed with: TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined which i cannot figure out the problem

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(
{
    url:url,
    success:function(httpResponse)
    {
      var Day = Parse.Object.extend("TestDay");
      var queryToday = new Parse.Query(Day);
      queryToday.equalTo("dayday", day);
      queryToday.equalTo("daymonth", month);
      queryToday.equalTo("dayyear", year);
      queryToday.equalTo("owner", theUser);
      queryToday.first().then(function(dayObject)  <---line 662
      {
         if(dayObject == undefined)
         {
           console.log("not found");
         }
         else
         {
           console.log(dayObject);
         }

      }, function(error)
      {

          console.log("first failed");
      });
    }
 });
```

Failed with: TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
    at Object.b.Query.first (Parse.js:1:57000)
    at Object.Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.success (main.js:662:48)

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that's the line? I mean, are you on web using the console?

Is there something else to know? Like are you working on a cloud function?

My guess is that returning `dayObject.save();` doesn't work. Try using a `console.log(dayObject)` to know exactly the query's response. It may happens that you'll have to use a conditional as follows:

```
if(dayObject == undefined){
    return Parse.Promise.error("Not Found");
}else{
    dayObject.increment("totalnumberofphotos");
    return dayObject.save();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is a background job function, and the console directly point to that line giving that error

Comment: And it doesn't matter if i use my code, or your code within that block, it gives the same error. i tried to clear all code within the then block and it still gives the same error.

Comment: my assumption is that, if first() has a result, it will invoke the first block after then, if there is no result, the error block will get invoked which i will create a brand new day

Comment: if it couldn't found an item it will still invoke success callback but `dayObject` will be null

Comment: yea, so even i changed the code to check if it is undefined, but at that line "queryToday.first().then(function(dayObject){ " still give the error "Cannot read property 'success' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question. it is because the parse sdk on cloud is too low version, so i have to update it to the latest one and it works now. thank you very much